# Disable SIP El capitan

Tags: terminal, osx-elcapitan

I have tried to disable SIP from OS X El Capitan following the procedure

- Enter Recovery Mode
- Open terminal
- `csrutil disable`

and it works fine, if I type `csrutil status` it is disabled.

Then I restart my computer, but in my terminal the `csrutil status` returns this

```
System Integrity Protection status: enabled (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
    Apple Internal: disabled
    Kext Signing: disabled
    Filesystem Protections: disabled
    Debugging Restrictions: disabled
    DTrace Restrictions: disabled
    NVRAM Protections: disabled

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.
```

Why is it still **enabled**? I need to disable it because otherwise the system won't recognize my Vodafone key in Vodafone Mobile Broadband.

Comment: I have edited your tag list: SIP tag is related to voip. It's not related to "System Integrity Protection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug. See https://openradar.appspot.com/22361698 ; that is listed as a duplicate of another bug but that other bug doesn't appear to be publicly accessible.